# UNION query for every raw in a table

Tags: sql, mariadb, set, union

Version of mariaDB
I have a table:

| USER | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 5 | 9 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 10 |

I want to count UNION set for user1 with every other user. For example user2 has set = 3 because user1 has

| USER | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

and user2 has

| USER | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 9 |

In teory it can be done like this

```
WITh user1_user2 AS (
SELECT * FROM user_categories
WHERE user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM user_categories
WHERE user_id = 2),
user1_user3 AS(
SELECT * FROM user_categories
WHERE user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM user_categories
WHERE user_id = 2)
```

But there are many users

FOR (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)
WITH THE
(2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 10),
(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10);
Should be something like this:
2 | 8
3 | 6
4 | 6
5 | 10

Comment: Can you also specify the final result?

Comment: Which MySQL/Mariadb version are you using? Do `select version();`.

Comment: 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: FOR 
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)
WITH THE 
 (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9),
    (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
    (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 10),
    (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10) ;

Should be something like this:
2 | 8
3 | 6
4 | 6
5 | 10

Comment: Please update your question, instead of answering in the comments.

Comment: Shouldn't `user1_user3` have `user_id = 3` (instead of `2`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could count the animals for each user, excluding the animals that user 1 already has, and then add the two together:

```sql
SELECT u.user, COUNT(uc.animal) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_categories WHERE user = 1) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM user_categories WHERE user <> 1) u
LEFT JOIN user_categories uc
    ON u.user = uc.user
   AND animal NOT IN (SELECT animal FROM user_categories WHERE user = 1)
GROUP BY u.user;
```

Outputs:

| user | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 10 |

Or you could:

```sql
SELECT u.user, COUNT(DISTINCT animal) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM user_categories WHERE user <> 1) AS u
JOIN user_categories uc ON uc.user IN (1, u.user)
GROUP BY u.user;
```

You can probably replace the `DISTINCT user` subqueries in both of these queries with your `users` table, but you did not include details.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sL-rmxTr).